# Tikz - How not style nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

New to using Tikz, i created tikz pictures I'd like to include in my latex document but latex keeps giving me a `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/none' and I am going to ignore it.` error because I don't want to color my nodes (no `fill` or `draw` color). I just wanted to make a line in my image but to make a line you need to connect two nodes so I don't really need the nodes and would prefer they stay invisible.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=none] (0) at (-1.5, 0) {};
        \node [style=none] (1) at (7.5, 0) {};
        \node [style=none] (2) at (-1.5, 1.75) {};
        \node [style=none] (6) at (0, 3) {};
        \node [style=none] (7) at (-0.5, 0) {};
        \node [style=none] (8) at (0, 0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw (0.center) to (1.center);
        \draw (6.center) to (8.center);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I get around this? I made a seperate style file as well but still didn't help.

(Note I'm using a mac app tikzit to make these things)

Comment: if you not like some style for nodes, just dropout this option: `node (0) at (-1.5, 0) {};`

Comment: seems better but getting now: `! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'nodelayer' is not part of the`
even though i have this:

`\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}`
`\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}`
`\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer, nodelayer}`

Comment: This works: `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer} 
 \pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
 \pgfsetlayers{main,nodelayer,edgelayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node  (0) at (-1.5, 0) {};
        \node  (1) at (7.5, 0) {};
        \node  (2) at (-1.5, 1.75) {};
        \node  (6) at (0, 3) {};
        \node  (7) at (-0.5, 0) {};
        \node  (8) at (0, 0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw (0.center) to (1.center);
        \draw (6.center) to (8.center);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: ... if you wrap it into `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, say.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yep that worked, thanks!

Comment: well, in my first comment is typo error, of course it should be `\node (0) at (-1.5, 0) {};` what @Schrödinger'scat  correctly spell out in his comment (answer).

Comment: @Zarko I guess the important thing is to add the layers. If you drop the backslash in `\node` this won't lead to the error message above.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, you are right. If OP will provide MWE, I will easy notice, what is missing in OP example ... Please, write answer instead just o comment!

Comment: you can include `\usepackage{tikzit}` in your preamble, the error refers to that. you can find the relevant documentation https://tikzit.github.io/#custom at File Formats section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide an official answer to the problem. As Zarko is saying, if you do not want to add a style, do not add a style, but use `none` only if you have defined a style of that name. Also, if you use layers, you need to define them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer} 
    \pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
    \pgfsetlayers{main,nodelayer,edgelayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node  (0) at (-1.5, 0) {};
        \node  (1) at (7.5, 0) {};
        \node  (2) at (-1.5, 1.75) {};
        \node  (6) at (0, 3) {};
        \node  (7) at (-0.5, 0) {};
        \node  (8) at (0, 0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw (0.center) to (1.center);
        \draw (6.center) to (8.center);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The ordering of the layers has been guessed here, a common problem when the code in the question is incomplete.